# openvidu video group-conference getting error of requested token gone wrng

Tags: node.js, openvidu

hie actually I'm kind of a newbie to the openvidu streaming. I'm following the openvidu official website to get the working of the project. I'm not pretty sure where I'm making mistake but getting an alert of the certificate. please help me to come over this. any helps thank you advance.

Answer (score 0):

> When you started OpenVidu server using
>   java -jar -Dopenvidu.secret=test_openvidu -Dopenvidu.publicurl=https://public_ip_address:4443/ openvidu-server-2.11.0.jar
>   command
>   Here -Dopenvidu.secret= test_openvidu so here my_secret is the secret key which we have given to server start and same key we have to use when we access OpenVidu server API

Comment: hi. thank you for your response. here i have used node js instead of java so my certificates are in .key and .crt format @priya Tarun

Comment: you dont have to put certificate when you start OpenVidu server you just need to give a secret password as authentication and same secret password you have to use when you start node server like node server.js https://your_public_ip:4443 your_secret

Comment: I have updated my question with the screenshot. I'm a newbie to openvidu please help me to come out of this. and I'm serving by -> http-server openvidu-tutorials/openvidu-getaroom/web

Comment: I got temporarily solution if you start server in another tab on address https://192.168.1.your_ip:4443 then logged in with username : OPENVIDUAPP password: test_openvidu

Comment: I'm nor getting an input tag for username nor for the password. as I showed question I',m getting an error of a certificate. @Priya Tarun

Comment: can you provide screen shot of error which you are getting @prasanna purohit

Comment: hie I had solved my issue. actually I was serving the node file without the docker up so I was getting an error. then I first made the docker up and given OPENVIDUAPP and MY_SECRET then I served node file. now everything is working fine. and thank you for your precious time and great response :-).

Comment: and as I showed in the screenshot the certificate error because of I was serving the docker file in server with the localhos id so i was getting that error. now everything is fine

Comment: also without docker you can up the openvidu media server.

Comment: yaa might be, but I don't have any idea about that. is there any other ways to achieve that?

Comment: you will get solution on this link https://openvidu.io/docs/deployment/deploying-ubuntu/